# Can't connect to Jfrog artifactory instance in GCP centos7 vm

Tags: linux, docker, google-cloud-platform, centos7, artifactory

I installed Jfrog artifactory as a docker container in GCP vm. But i am unable to access it through external ip. both http and https is enabled. i was able to curl localhost but can't access from browser. How do i troubleshoot this?

```
[sksabit_faisal@instance-1 ~]$ systemctl status artifactory
● artifactory.service - Setup Systemd script for Artifactory Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/artifactory.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-08-29 06:08:38 UTC; 17min ago
 Main PID: 1402 (docker)
    Tasks: 8
   Memory: 72.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/artifactory.service
           └─1402 /usr/bin/docker run --name artifactory -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 -v /jfrog/artifactory:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest

Aug 29 06:24:55 instance-1 docker[1402]: [168B blob data]
Aug 29 06:24:55 instance-1 docker[1402]: [205B blob data]
Aug 29 06:24:55 instance-1 docker[1402]: [176B blob data]
Aug 29 06:24:55 instance-1 docker[1402]: [253B blob data]
Aug 29 06:24:55 instance-1 docker[1402]: [202B blob data]
Aug 29 06:24:55 instance-1 docker[1402]: [209B blob data]
Aug 29 06:24:55 instance-1 docker[1402]: [168B blob data]
Aug 29 06:24:55 instance-1 docker[1402]: [205B blob data]
Aug 29 06:25:03 instance-1 docker[1402]: 2022-08-29T06:25:03.160Z [jffe ] [INFO ] [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - fetchAndUpdateAllConfi...onfigurations
Aug 29 06:25:33 instance-1 docker[1402]: 2022-08-29T06:25:33.159Z [jffe ] [INFO ] [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - fetchAndUpdateAllConfi...onfigurations
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
[sksabit_faisal@instance-1 ~]$ ss -tunelp | grep 8081
tcp    LISTEN     0      128       *:8081                  *:*                   ino:28010 sk:ffff8e4bb3c72e80 <->
tcp    LISTEN     0      128    [::]:8081               [::]:*                   ino:27367 sk:ffff8e4c37940840 v6only:1 <->
[sksabit_faisal@instance-1 ~]$ 


[sksabit_faisal@instance-1 ~]$ curl -v http://localhost:8081/artifactory
* About to connect() to localhost port 8081 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8081 (#0)
> GET /artifactory HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost:8081
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 
< Location: /artifactory/
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 29 Aug 2022 06:29:58 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: The firewall rule for http is port 80 and https is port 443. You need to create a firewall rule for port 8081 and assign that rule via network tags to the VM instance.

Comment: Thanks. it worked.
Anyway i tried with ngrok to host port and it worked as well. don't know why firewall allowed that.

Answer (score 1):

as what @John Hanley suggested creating a firewall rule.

see the steps on [Creating Firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules):

1. From your navigation menu go to the Firewall page.
2. Click **Create firewall rule.**
3. Enter a **Name** for the firewall rule.
   This name must be unique for the project.
4. (Optional) You can enable firewall rules logging:

- Click **Logs > On.**
- To omit metadata, expand **Logs details** and then clear **Include metadata.**

5. Specify the **Network** for the firewall rule.
6. Specify the **Priority** of the rule.

- The lower the number, the higher the priority.

7. For the **Direction of traffic**, choose ingress or egress.
8. For the **Action on match**, choose allow or deny.
9. Specify the **Targets** of the rule.

- If you want the rule to apply to all instances in the network, choose `All instances in the network.`
- If you want the rule to apply to select instances by network (target) tags, choose `Specified target tags,` then type the tags to which the rule should apply into the **Target tags** field.
- If you want the rule to apply to select instances by associated service account, choose `Specified service account,` indicate whether the service account is in the current project or another one under **Service account scope**, and choose or type the service account name in the **Target service account** field.

10. For an ingress rule, specify the **Source filter**:

- To filter incoming traffic by source IPv4 ranges, select `IPv4 ranges` and enter the CIDR blocks into the **Source IPv4 ranges** field. Use `0.0.0.0/0` for any IPv4 source.
- To filter incoming traffic by source IPv6 ranges, select `IPv6 ranges` and enter the CIDR blocks into the **Source IPv6 ranges** field. Use `::/0` for any IPv6 source.

11. For an egress rule, specify the **Destination filter**:

- To filter outgoing traffic by destination IPv4 ranges, select `IPv4 ranges` and enter the CIDR blocks into the **Destination IPv4 ranges** field. Use `0.0.0.0/0` for any IPv4 destination.
- To filter outgoing traffic by destination IPv6 ranges, select IPv6 ranges and enter the CIDR blocks into the **Destination IPv6 ranges** field. Use `::/0` for any IPv6 destination.

12. Define the **Protocols and ports** to which the rule applies:

- Select `Allow all` or `Deny all`, depending on the action, to have the rule apply to all protocols and destination ports.
- Define specific protocols and destination ports:
- Select **tcp** to include the TCP protocol and destination ports. Enter all or a comma-delimited list of destination ports, such as `20-22, 80, 8080.`
- Select **udp** to include the UDP protocol and destination ports. Enter all or a comma-delimited list of destination ports, such as `67-69, 123.`
- Select **Other protocols** to include protocols such as `icmp`, `sctp`, or a protocol number. Use protocol `58` for ICMPv6. See protocols and destination ports for more information.

13. (Optional) You can create the firewall rule but not enforce it by setting its enforcement state to disabled. Click **Disable rule**, then select **Disabled**.
14. Click **Create.**